# If $m$ and $n$ women are standing toghter ]such that no men are woman are adjacent together what are the number of Permutations

Tags: permutations

suppose $m$ men and $n$ women from a single line in such a way that no two men are next to each other and no women are next to each other how many lineup are possible ?

Never solved these problems before with $m$ and $n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is only possible if $m=n$ or $n \pm 1$

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding of your question is okay then no lineups are possible if $|m-n|>1$.

If $|m-n|=1$ then there are $m!n!$ possibilities.

If $m=n$ then there are $2m!n!=2n!n!=2m!m!$ possibilities. Factor $2$ because the person most left can be a man or a woman.

Comment: I agree this answer but I wonder why diffrent people are giving different answers

Comment: No, this is correct.

Comment: I think the answers are the same now.